# Integer data type with more that 10 digits

Tags: c++, turbo-c

I am using the `long` type for storing values but it doesn't store a number with more than 10 digits.

Is there any way to make a new integer type with extended memory size (e.g. 12 bytes or more)?

Comment: Sure, just define a class, like `class ReallybigInt{ ...};`, you just need to define how it is supposed to work in the class.

Comment: [Google search.](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=CtgHWuXPHtO2jwPA1onIDQ&q=bigint+c%2B%2B&oq=BigInt+C%2B%2B&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.0l5j0i22i30k1l5.1633.8522.0.15772.11.10.0.0.0.0.99.591.10.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..1.10.588.0..0i131k1j0i10k1.0.sFD451JBL0U)

Comment: Do you really need 12-bytes?  Or do you just want integers with more than 10-digits?

Comment: more than 10 digits anyhow

Comment: whenever I input a number having more than 10 digits (store in long long) .... it stores a garbage value but works fine for 10 digits and lower

Comment: Add the code for your non-working program.

Comment: turbo c is a 16 bit compiler so a 32 bit int is the biggest ( http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~nikol/material/types_sizes.pdf and http://www.itlnet.net/programming/program/Reference/tc/ng71ec0.html and http://ltcpp.blogspot.co.nz/2012/07/c-data-types-variables-constants.html). If you need bigger you can use a arbitrary precision number library like GNU GMP ( https://gmplib.org/ ) or you get a 32bit or 64bit compiler.  Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085435/how-to-use-long-long-keyword-in-turbo-c-3-2-compiler and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486893/long-integer-problem

Comment: If you want to use turbo c then you will need an arbitrary precision library.  There is a list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software

Answer (score 1):

Use a `long long` (or `unsigned long long`), which is 64-bits and has a range of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Range_of_values

Comment: Note that a 64-bit integer is only 8 bytes, but the question is looking for a 12+ byte integer instead.

Comment: That's true, but the question also wants to "store a number with more than 10 digits", which this does.

Comment: I tried long long but it does not store a 11 digit number or larger

Comment: @AryaSudan sure it does, here's an example: https://repl.it/repls/PricklyBasicBaiji

Comment: Turbo C, Oh no!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an implementation of [arbitrary precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic), which will allow you to store as many digits as you want, <s>or use Python</s>. You will have to implement basic arithmetics from scratch, but once you get its point, it won't be too hard.

The standard guarantees `long long` to be at least 8 bytes long. If you want a 8-byte integer, try this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t a;
uint64_t b; // Unsigned 64-bit int
```

If your compiler complains that it doesn't know what `int64_t` is, then there's no luck unless you implement an [AP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enter https://github.com/cerevra/int/tree/master/v2](https://github.com/cerevra/int/tree/master/v2)

It`s a [proposal](https://cerevra.github.io/int/) to C++20, but it could be useful with modern c++14 compatible compilers too